# Elasticsearch showing yellow health for logstash index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

```
The health column is showing yellow for logstash index , even after deleting old ones they re recreated with yellow health. I have clusters for this setup and have checked shards using below.

GET _cluster/health :

{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 12,
  "active_shards" : 22,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 3,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 88.46153846153845
}
```

Any idea how this can be turned to green ?
Also the index are not getting created daily due to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow health indicates that your primary shard is allocated but the replicas are not allocated. This may be because your elastic is deployed using one node only. Elastic does not allocate the primary and the replica shards on the same node as it will serve no purpose. When you have multiple nodes and multiples shards, the elastic by default allocates the primary and the replicas to different nodes.

As seen from the data you provided, you have 22 active shards and only 2 nodes. The unassigned shards, i.e., 3, is the problem leading to yellow cluster health.

In order to solve this, you can do 2 things.

1. If you are using elastic for testing, you can initiate the server with one shard (no replicas). In this case you have one node in your elastic service.
2. If you are in a production and want multiple shards (primary + replicas), then the number of nodes should be equal to the total number of shards. For instance, if you have 1 primary and 2 replicas, then initiate the server with 3 nodes.

Please remember to do this when you are initiating your elastic server.

The harm in yellow health is that if your primary shard goes bad, you will lose the service and the data as well.

Comment: Hi fam....can you please suggest so what changes do I have to make ? should I increase my nodes and to which number . Should i increase number of nodes to 3 ?

Comment: You can have a detailed look at your shards by `GET /_cat/shards`. As discussed, the total number of nodes should be primary + all_replicas.

Comment: With only two nodes your cluster is not resilient and do not support any failure, if your master went down, the other cluster wont work either, so there is no need for replicas. The best thing to do is to add 1 more node and change your replicas number to just 2.

Also, in a 3 nodes cluster, all your nodes need to be master eligible as well.

If you don't want to add another node, you can just change your replicas to 0 as there are no need for them.